# Why cannot see internal test option in test flight when deploying Expo project

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I am new to IOS development, I upload a build on app store. From many tutorial I found online, in the testflight tab, I am supposed to see the internal test option, but my testflight tab looks very different from others. Please anyone has any idea?

Expected:
[image]
Mine:
[image]

Comment: Aren't those example names of tester groups? You can create and name them as you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you upload a build for testflight and approve the missing compliance, the build automatically goes for internal testing. The users who are added to your appstore connect users, immidietly get the build for testing. For this only 25 persons at max can test.
You can add more users in appstore connect by going to users and access in the homepage

[image]

And then by clicking on that  you can add the users as below by filling this form ,

[image]

Then you need to go to MyApps and clickof appstoreconnect users:

[image]

[image]

then you can click of plus sign + and select the tester and add it and as soon as you add, he/she will get an invite code for testflight and voila. thats it. they have the build.

[image]

If you want to add external testers to test, first your build needs to be approved.

Hope its clear. Feel free for doubts

Comment: Hey @alex, glad it helped you. If you think it's the correct answer. Please mark the answer as accepted so that it can help others.

Comment: ah yeah. very useful. Sorry I am new, let me find where is the accept button